# "exists" function while checking for hash value existence

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to replace every occurrence of "EXECUTE func-name" with "#  EXECUTE func-name. *followed by a hash value*" ONLY if the func-name exists. My regex below doesn't seem to agree with me.

```
s/EXECUTE ([\w-]+)\.?/"#  EXECUTE $1.\n" . $hash{$1}/eg if (exists($hash{$1}));
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well your code executes the `if`-condition before the actual regex, so you probably get a warning when executing your code.

When using the `e`-modifier you can use perl-code in the "replacement-part" directly:

```
s/EXECUTE\s+([\w-]+)\.?/
    if(exists($hash{$1})) {
        "#  EXECUTE $1.\n" . $hash{$1}
    } else {
        $&
    }/xeg;
```

I have added /x, so you can format the regexp to make it actually readable - but now you have to match the whitespace explicitly (that's why I've added `\s+` between `EXECUTE` and the group). The `$&` represents the whole match (so if there is no hash-entry for `$1`, nothing is changed).

---

That said, using `$&` slows down every match and substitution without captures in your entire program. Here's an improvement:

```
s/(EXECUTE\s+([\w-]+)\.?)/
    if(exists($hash{$2})) {
        "#  EXECUTE $2.\n" . $hash{$2}
    } else {
        $1
    }/xeg;
```

Comment: That was Brutally Brilliant..!! :-)  Thanks a ton!